# alternative to .successor() in swift?

Tags: swift

```
let greeting = "Guten Tag!"

greeting[greeting.startIndex.successor()] 
// "u"

greeting[greeting.startIndex.successor().successor().successor()]
// "e"
```

is there any alternative to this rather than writing `.successor()` many times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **Swift 2.0** this is `advancedBy`:

```
greeting[greeting.startIndex.advancedBy(3)]  // "e"
```

In **Swift 1.2**:

```
greeting[advance(greeting.startIndex, 3)]  // "e"
```

Comment: thanks!! turns out I realized I'm still in swift 1.2

Comment: Time to update.  Xcode 7 is now in the Mac app store.